# Best Linux distro for Cherokee?

Tags: linux, php, cherokee, distro

I want to use Cherokee for my PHP-centered site...what distro would best for that?

Answer (score 4):

The definitive answer: whichever distro you're most comfortable with.

Case closed.

Answer (score 1):

This is really an opinionated question and it boils down to what you ultimately are trying to do/need for this php-centered site. I personally recommend CentOS as it's package manager YUM has Cherokee available for install. It's also based of RedHat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) which centers itself around stability. However if you're looking for having the most recent versions of things available with little tinkering might I suggest something like Ubuntu Server Edition as Ubuntu tends to offer the most up-to-date versions of software whereas RHEL typically tends to sticks to LTS releases or the oldest supported stable version of software.

http://centos.org/

http://ubuntu.com/server

Comment: Why would you recommend Ubuntu Server over Debian? I personally would much rather use a tried-and-true server distro...

Comment: I went through two spectrums - CentOS which is a tried and true server distro, and Ubuntu the "feel-good" distro. One is stable and rigorous the other has pretty graphics and is relatively well supported by its community.

Comment: @ErikA do you think Ubuntu Server is slower than Debian? If not, why do you think one should recommend Debian over Ubuntu Server?

Answer (score 0):

[**FreeBSD**](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/cvsweb.cgi/ports/www/cherokee/)*... Just saying...

Seriously any of the ones [listed as having packages](http://www.cherokee-project.com/downloads.html) are probably good candidates.

*I *know* it's not Linux